# Need help running Python app as service in Ubuntu with Upstart

Tags: python, ubuntu, upstart

I have written a logging application in Python that is meant to start at boot, but I've been unable to start the app with [Ubuntu's Upstart init daemon](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).  When run from the terminal with **sudo /usr/local/greeenlog/main.pyw**, the application works perfectly.  Here is what I've tried for the Upstart job:

**/etc/init/greeenlog.conf**

```
# greeenlog

description     "I log stuff."

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
    exec /usr/local/greeenlog/main.pyw
end script
```

My application starts one child thread, in case that is important.  I've tried the job with the **expect fork** stanza without any change in the results.  I've also tried this with **sudo** and without the script statements (just a lone exec statement).  In all cases, after boot, running **status greeenlog** returns **greeenlog stop/waiting** and running **start greeenlog** returns:

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.61" (uid=1000 pid=2496 comm="start) interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init"))
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I appreciate any help you can give.  Thanks.

Comment: When you try `sudo start greeenlog`, does the error message still say `(uid=1000 pid=2496 comm="start)`? By the way, I set up a /etc/init/greeenlog.conf as you described, and was successful with the command `sudo start greeenlog`.

Comment: Good call!  sudo start greeenlog returns greeenlog start/running, process 2609, but the application doesn't really start and nothing is logged.  A subsequent call to status greeenlog returns greeenlog stop/waiting.  Again, the app runs perfectly with sudo /usr/local/greeenlog/main.pyw.  What am I missing?

Comment: It sounds like `main.pyw` might be crashing when run through upstart. Perhaps try putting `exec /usr/local/greeenlog/main.pyw >/tmp/main.out 2>&1` in `greeenlog.conf` so you can see some error messages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to unutbu's help, I have been able to correct my job.  Apparently, these are the only environment variables that Upstart sets (retrieved in Python with **os.environ**):

```
{'TERM': 'linux', 'PWD': '/', 'UPSTART_INSTANCE': '', 'UPSTART_JOB': 'greeenlog', 'PATH': '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin'}
```

My program relies on a couple of these variables being set, so here is the revised job with the right environment variables:

```
# greeenlog

description     "I log stuff."

start on startup
stop on shutdown

env DISPLAY=:0.0
env GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/greeenguru/.gtkrc-1.2-gnome2

script
    exec /usr/local/greeenlog/main.pyw > /tmp/greeenlog.out 2>&1
end script
```

Thank you!