# Running a Python service on ubuntu using upstart

Tags: ubuntu, service, heartbeat, upstart

I want to create to deploy a heartbeat service (a python script) as a service using Upstart.

My understanding is that I've to add a `/etc/init/myheartbeatservice.conf` with the following contents.

```
# my heartbeat service 

description     "Heartbeat monitor"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
    exec /path/to/my/python/script.py
end script
```

My script starts another service process and the monitors the processes and sends heartbeat to an outside server regularly. Are `startup` and `shutdown` the correct events ? 
Also my script create a new thread. I'm assuming I also need to add `fork daemon` to my conf file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upstart only sets a handful of environment variables. Does your application need any of these set?

See this answer to a similar question: [Need help running Python app as service in Ubuntu with Upstart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2646616/15985)